# How to fetch data from database using two different date in php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
date1 = 10/1/2015
date2 = 10/13/2015`
```

How to fetch data from database using these two dates? I want to fetch all the data that was entered from 1 to 13 october. How can I do it using php or SQL? Please guide me to write the SQL queries.

Database design

```
id       name       date
1        Ram        10/1/2015
2        shyam      10/2/2015
3        hari       10/13/2015
4        gita       10/14/2015</pre>
```

I want to select and show first 3 id which are listed between `1st oct` to `13th oct` and don't want to show 14th oct value. Please help me. Looking forward for the help. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Please have a look at [MySQL BETWEEN ... AND ... operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

Comment: First update the schema to use proper Date type for your date field, then run a simple `between` comparison using the right formats

Comment: convert your date to mysql date format.

Comment: Right,  search for BETWEEN. You can also use <, >, <=, >= compare on dates in WHERE

Answer (score 2):

Date format in MySQL is [`yyyy-MM-dd`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). So, the query should be -

```
select * from test where date between '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-13';
```

If you want to use a different format to fetch your data then you can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Your query will look like this.

```
select * from test where date between STR_TO_DATE('26-10-2012', '%d-%m-%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('28-10-2012', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use mysql_query function to send query, LIMIT 3 for showing 3 rows and  BETWEEN Condition to check the range. Also rather  BETWEEN Condition you can use greater than (>=) & less than(<=) bindrelational operators. But your database date column shouldbe in date format.

```
$result = mysql_query("select id from test where date between '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-13' LIMIT 3 ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {  
      echo $row['id'];
   }
```