# SQL query date range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
ID      DATE_START DATE_END
------- ---------- --------
11944   10.01.15   20.01.15
```

I would like to select rows based an a date range, e.g

1. `01.01.15 - 25.01.15`
2. `15.01.15 - 25.01.15`

In both cases I would like to select the column mentioned above. Is this possible with SQL? I tried a few things but i don't get the second query working. I use Oracle DB:

Example usage:
I want to query ma datatable like this: Show me all Entries between `15.01.15` and `25.01.15`. This should yield to row with ID `11944`

Comment: Do you mean something like here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117593/how-to-fetch-data-from-database-using-two-different-date-in-php

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas it depends on his locale configuration. It is perfectly fine for brazilian date format as an example.

Comment: What data type are your "date" columns? And when you say you can't get a query working, it's really helpful if you can post the actual query, and describe what you expect it to do, and what's happening instead.

Answer (score 2):

You want to return a row if two periods overlap, assuming both columns are  defined as `DATE`.

```
select *
from tab
where DATE_START <= DATE '2015-01-25' -- end of searched period
  and DATE_END   >= DATE '2015-01-15' -- begin of searched period
```

In Standard SQL there's an `OVERLAPS` predicate which is not (officially) supported by Oracle:

```
where (DATE_START, DATE_END) OVERLAPS (DATE '2015-01-15', DATE '2015-01-25')
```

Comment: your statement would not work if I would set my search range to 2012-01-01 - 2020-01-01

Comment: Of course it will, double check your query: `Start1 <= End2 and End1 >= Start2`

Comment: @matthias What is the data type of the two columns?